# Apply class to @Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage="Please enter student name.")]
[StringLength(20,ErrorMessage="Student name cannot be over 20 characters long")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.StudentName,new {@class = "validation"})
```

Seems like there is no such overload for `ValidationMessageFor`. How do I apply class to it?

Comment: The HTML markup for that should be a class name called `text-danger` and `field-validation-error`.. try adding CSS to those class names

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I couldn't find those classes. Are they located in ~/Content/Blue.css? My framework is MVC4.

Comment: I meant when you view the page in IE or Chrome, you right click on the element and hit 'Inspect' and that will show you html markup for that element. try what rosdi answered.. you might have to put `!important` after

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just looked [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object,System.String%29) up.

So in your case try:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.StudentName,""/* or null or what you want the error message to be */, new { @class = "validation" })
```

Comment: Didn't the second parameter erase the original error message?

Comment: @DylanChensky You can change that as you please.. I personally put error messages within my model with the `Required` attribute.

Comment: What if I have 2 messages for 2 errors respectively? See question update please.

Comment: @DylanChensky Yes it should work.. on one of my models I use both `[StringLength]` and `[Required]` with my `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` and they both show their respective error messages based on the error

Comment: @DylanChensky was this able to assist you?

Comment: I am checking. Will get back to you later.

Comment: I don't understand why this got so many upvotes, this will clear an error messages.

Comment: This is not clearing my dynamic error messages - so it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

By default it should be using `.field-validation-error` class.

All you have to do is customize that css.

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: red;
}
```

If you really want to change that class name to 'validation', then I do not know how.

Comment: I tried F12 Dom inspector and searched in the solution explorer, cannot find this class.

Comment: that class (applied to a span) will only display once the `ModelState` comes back invalid, which is why you won't be able to see it if validation hasn't already occurred.